# Does separation of the business logic from presentation logic increase the security?

Tags: security, jsp, servlets

We can seperate the business logic from presentation logic in jsp .It facilitates to write the java code inside a html environment if we use servlets then we need to write the html tags inside out.write() number of times. In which cases it is not possible to combines the businesslogic and presentation logic? And why it reduces security ?

Comment: It's always possible. And it doesn't have anything to do with security (although, if the code is a mess, there's a good chance that security handling is like the code)

Comment: There are three questions here. Which are you asking?

Comment: I read in book that when we combines the businesslogic and presentation logic it reduces security ,is it true ?